# Pagination by anchor in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pagination, anchor

**Table and data:**

```
CREATE TABLE baz (
  id   VARCHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO baz
  VALUES 
    ('uSzZcsUYy4YqkUCG', 'item1'),
    ('QapJ0QFc4k0o5qxK', 'item2'),
    ('yu0CqLxE0CeWKa0K', 'item3'),
    ('MeRYVkZn48n8nnYt', 'item4'),
    ('C1AKwyURqXU0uzl3', 'item5'),
    ('D5wWuhYPvuGwEuNu', 'item6'),
    ('Ht9C6LqfqxBmuBmt', 'item7'),
    ('DWFMD2LceD9ADwmA', 'item8'),
    ('43kw43SOLGUcBQuZ', 'item9')
  ;
```

**Problem:**

Imagine that this 'baz' table is already a result of a select (for example I have a playlist for user and this is a tracks from the playlist of particular user ordered by some rules). All id's is unique and not sorted in alphabetical order. I want to make pagination based on anchor (particular id from this table). For example user want to select next 5 records from this table starting from id 'yu0CqLxE0CeWKa0K' (or may be 5 previous records).

**Solutions:**

1. Find row number for particular id and then select next/previous N items

   ```
   WITH ranked_baz AS
     (SELECT *, row_number() OVER () AS row_number FROM baz)
   SELECT id, name FROM ranked_baz
   WHERE row_number > (SELECT row_number FROM ranked_baz where id = 'yu0CqLxE0CeWKa0K')
   LIMIT 10;
   ```

   Cons:

   - need to write two SQL requests (one to select next rows, and another to select previous rows)
   - as I know postgresql window performance degrades on big tables
2. Create cursor for this table and move them to find anchor and then take next or previous N items

   Cons:

   - seems like it's not productive solution for big tables (millions of records)

Comment: row_number is always 1, you never find a row that has a different row_number.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, sorry, this request is just an example, so I forgot to modify it. Fixed. But common problem with pagination still exists.

Comment: solution #1 is conceptually flawed because it fails to order the rows explicitly. It has to assume that the next query will present the rows in the same order than the previous one, and that  assumption is wishful thinking.